# Docker Compose getting error ECONNREFUSED 192.168.65.2:3306 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to setup some containers for my MySQL environment by using Docker Compose in a Windows 10 host, but I am getting an ECONNREFUSED error:

```
"{\"message\":\"connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.65.2:3306\",\"stack\":\"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.65.2:3306\\n    at Object.createConnection (/var/task/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:242:31)\\n    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:47:37)\\n    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:74:25)\"}"Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

here is the function I am trying to setup using sam local

```
RDSHandlerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub 'RDSHandler'
      CodeUri: ./src/RDSHandler
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Tags:
        Application: helloWorld
      Policies:
      - Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
            - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
            - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
            - kms:Decrypt
            - kms:DescribeKey
            - kms:GenerateDataKey
          Resource: '*'
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - rds-db:connect
          Resource: '*'
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DB_REGION: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
          DB_NAME: 'test'
          HTTP_PROXY: ""
          HTTPS_PROXY: ""RDSHandlerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub 'RDSHandler'
      CodeUri: ./src/RDSHandler
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Tags:
        Application: helloWorld
      Policies:
      - Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
            - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
            - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
            - kms:Decrypt
            - kms:DescribeKey
            - kms:GenerateDataKey
          Resource: '*'
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - rds-db:connect
          Resource: '*'
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DB_REGION: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
          DB_NAME: 'test'
          HTTP_PROXY: ""
          HTTPS_PROXY: ""
```

I am kind of new to Docker Compose, but I have tried many things like changing the output port to 3307, nothing seem to work. Any help?